# Why gcc will optimise an if statement but not a question mark operator?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization

With the following code, compiled with -O3,

```
extern int*  source;
extern int*  dest;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // dest conditionally written
    if (*source)
    {
        *dest = *source;
    }

    // dest always written?
    *dest = *source ? *source : *dest;
}
```

gcc generates code that writes to dest in A when `*source != 0`, but it generates code that always writes to dest for B, even when `*source == 0`, ie it generates effectively `*dest = *dest`, which is redundant. What's the reasoning for this and is there a way to improve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it the extern that’s causing it?

Comment: Please show the assembly code your talking about, so we don't need to guess.

Comment: Playground for this: https://godbolt.org/g/3q9sDz

Comment: the operator is `?:`, not `?` alone

Comment: BTW: both codes A and B are not equivalent:but [here](https://godbolt.org/g/9KdwuS) I modified my previous sample so that both codes are equivalent, but the code that uses `if` still does not write to `*dest` if `*source` is 0.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The better equivalent would be `int const value = *source ? *source : *dest; *dest = value;` or if that stored into intermediate value: `int value; if(*source){ value = *source; }else{ value = *dest; } *dest = value;`

Comment: [Intel compiler will generate the same code in both cases](https://godbolt.org/g/qYxd44). I guess other compilers are just not optimizing enough.

Comment: And clang always reads both and writes, but uses cmov instead of a branch.

Comment: And VC++ uses the condition to move the pointer into a register, then read from that, i.e. it does `*dest = *(*source ? source : dest)`